# How to subscribe plain/text response in angular

Tags: angular, httpclient

My post API is returning **plain lorem ipsum text**, but the payload is in JSON format.
my problem is I am not getting the response in the main block of a subscriber, but able to view the response in the error block.
Pls, help me to get a fix.

here is my code snippet.

```
const path = 'sample URL';
const body = { 
   id: 'xyz',
   name: 'abc'
};
const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders(
        {
          'Accept': 'text/plain',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'responseType': 'text'

        })};
this.http.post(path, body, httpOptions).subscribe(
  (res)=>{ },
  err=>{ 
    console.log("===",err);
  }
);
```

I also tried res.text() but not worked.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` in `res`? If you can also post the `err` log.

Comment: it's coming directly inside err block, 
In the network tab of browser status code is 200 and able to see the response.

Comment: What about `ok`, is it false?

Comment: If you don't know how to check it, you can do it in the browser console, it should be after the `status`. Something like `ok: false`

Comment: My question is because if the server does not respond in the JSON format the response will have a wierd status 200 OK and the `ok` field will be false, subscribe will take this as an error response regardless of the status code, set reponse to null and pass the response to the error lambda.

Comment: @NeerajShrimali did you check my answer provided below. I identified your mistake and provided corrected code.

Comment: @anastaciu ok is also true. thanks for your attention, my issue is get resolved with Shabbir's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in your code. Response Type is not part of headers. Its another option like header. See code below that will work for you.

```
const path = 'sample URL';
const body = {
  id: 'xyz',
  name: 'abc'
};
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  })
this.http.post(path, body, {headers, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((res) => {
```

Comment: Thanks, Shabbir, it's working... sorry for the delay in response actually I asked this question on behalf of my one friend who is facing this issue, so was waiting for his response.

Comment: Glad that help and good that you helping your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the response type of the request using the following code:

`this.http.post(URL, body, {responseType: 'text'})`

Comment: Sorry, I just update my Question, I also tried with  {responseType: 'text'} but was not working.